# Is it a good idea to use Workers for checking events?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I mean, let's say an User signs up and buy a monthly membership. Is it a good idea set a job to run in a month to see if the user renewed his membership and take appropriate actions? Is there a better or a more "Railsy" way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put it in a rake job that you execute daily (or hourly on heroku or whatever).

```
task :cron => :environment do
  desc "Daily and Monthly tasks tasks"

  # monthly tasks
  if Date.today.day == 1  
    puts "monthly status check - #{Time.now}"
    Rake::Task["your_task"].invoke
  end
end
```